# UWP package.appmanifest Asset generator scales up my image

Tags: windows, uwp

I am trying to create the visual assets for a UWP Windows 10 app. Using VS 2017 (15.2, 26430.6) and the package.appmanifest. When I place a 400x400 .png image into the asset generator, the size it recommends, it is scaling it up to 533x533 automatically, which is causing distortion and artifacts. The prompt does not support SVG (though it does support other vector graphic formats, namely .pdf and .ai).

In case it matters, I originally placed a 327x327 (which I thought might have been the source of the scaling). But I have since closed my solution and reopened and the scaling is still there.

Edit: Created blank new app. Placed same 400x400 image in Asset Generator and it still scales to 533x533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested Asset Generator according to your description. But I can not reproduce your issue. It seems that there is some issue with the Asset Generator you create the visual assets with.

> When I place a 400x400 .png image into the asset generator, the size it recommends, it is scaling it up to 533x533 automatically, which is causing distortion and artifacts. The prompt does not support SVG (though it does support other vector graphic formats, namely .pdf and .ai).

If you want to use svg file to avoid scaling problems. You could use [The UWP Visual Assets Generator tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterR.UWPVisualAssetsGenerator) of Visual Studio. And it can create all the visual assets needed for an UWP app. You can also choose the width of your icon within the asset.

[image]

For more detail please refer to [UWP Visual Assets Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterR.UWPVisualAssetsGenerator).